# Blank pages after grunt clean

Tags: magento2, grunt

I've set up an new theme in Magento 2 and everything was looking fine. I installed Grunt and changed all necessary files (I think) I then did the following: Grunt clean, grunt exec:myTheme, grunt less:myThem and grunt watch.

The grunt watch seems to be working but now when i reload the page It's blank. looked at page source an theres nothing there. Also the same has happened to the admin side as well.

Any ideas as to what it could be. If you need to see certain files I will post.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting read/write permissions in the root of the magento file

```
chown -R :www-data .
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```